# iOS: NSXMLParser error on iOS 6 (code 100)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

in my iOS application I make a call to the WS which returns an xml response. I parse it using NSXMLParser. Everything was working OK on iOS 6 until the webservice changed a little bit. Now I keep getting this error for iOS 6:

> The following error has occurred: The operation couldn't be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 100.) (code: 100)

But, when I tried on iOS 7 everything worked just fine. Below are the xml responses:

**OLD xml response:**

```
<User 
  xmlns="MyService.Rest.A3.Entities" 
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FirstName>George</FirstName>
  <LastName>McQuillan</LastName>
  <Username>usename</Username>
</User>
```

**NEW xml response:**

```
<User 
   xmlns="http://www.MyService.Rest.A3.Entities" 
   xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <FirstName>George</FirstName>
   <LastName>McQuillan</LastName>
   <Username>usename</Username>
</User>
```

So the new response works only on iOS 7, on iOS 6 it doesn't. I noticed that the first xmlns from old response is not a link, but why does it work for iOS 7 then?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with new xml response ?

Comment: @Emmanuel You can reproduce the problem with the first one.

Comment: @Rob Yes, seems that old and new responses been mixed up.

Comment: @Rob But even if `-parser:parseErrorOccurred:` is send, the `-parse` method return YES. And I can parse the whole sample.

Comment: @Emmanuel Agreed, which is why in my answer below, I suggested that if she can't fix the XML, she should simply gracefully ignore this warning.

Comment: @Rob Agreed, seems a harmless error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experience the exact opposite, where the `xmlns="MyService.Rest.A3.Entities"` rendition calls `parseErrorOccurred` in iOS 6, but not in iOS 7. And in my tests, the `xmlns="http://www.MyService.Rest.A3.Entities"` rendition succeeds in both iOS 6 and 7.

`NSXMLParser` in iOS 6 appears to validate whether the namespace is a valid absolute URI. iOS 7 does not. The namespace with `xmlns="MyService.Rest.A3.Entities"` is not a valid absolute URI. If you run that through `xmllint` (a command line program available on the Mac via the Terminal app), it will also report that that namespace is not valid:

```
$ xmllint old.xml 

old.xml:2: namespace warning : xmlns: URI MyService.Rest.A3.Entities is not absolute
  xmlns="MyService.Rest.A3.Entities" 
                                    ^
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<User xmlns="MyService.Rest.A3.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FirstName>George</FirstName>
  <LastName>McQuillan</LastName>
  <Username>usename</Username>
</User>
```

Fortunately this error is informational only, and the parsing continues, so if you're stuck with this XML, you might just want to gracefully detect and ignore it, e.g.:

```
if (!([error.domain isEqualToString:NSXMLParserErrorDomain] && error.code == 100)) {
    // do your error handling here, ignoring `NSXMLParserErrorDomain` code 100
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

It's probably better to fix the XML so that it has a valid URI.

---

By the way, the [XML Namespaces Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) points out that the use of a relative URI has been deprecated and that a namespace value should either be empty or an absolute URI. So, it's understandable why iOS 6 reports the error, but given that `parseErrorOccurred` is intended for fatal errors only, the iOS 7 behavior is probably more correct, no longer calling this method for this non-fatal warning.

Comment: Thank you very much for enlightening me! Your answer really helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the following NSXMLParserDelegate method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

Then you can log the NSError and determine what it believes is occurring. Of course it might give you the same error code 100 as you are receiving but it might have more useful information inside of it.

Comment: I already implement this method. The problem is that it shouldn't return an error as on iOS 7 works.